# Trying to Implement wp_editor Along With a Save Button in a Custom Template

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-editor

I've created a new WordPress template that allows me to edit posts and certain meta values from the frontend. I managed to include the WYSIWYG editor using the *wp_edit()* function.

However, I don't seem to find a way to update the data from this editor. I've tried with the *wp_update_post()* function, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php

$post_id = 308;
$post = get_post( $post_id, OBJECT, 'edit' );

$content = $post->post_content;
$editor_id = 'my_editor';

wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );

 if(isset($_POST['content']))    {   $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 308,
      'post_content' => stripslashes($content),   );

  wp_update_post( $my_post ); 

header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP-SELF'].'');

}

?>
```

And here's the form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP-SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

<input type="submit" name="content" value="Save post" />

</form>
```

I've also checked out this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181688/add-a-wp-editor-to-custom-plugin-and-save-data), but in my case I just want to update the post content, not a meta value.

Thanks in advance!